# Are questions about SP installation and setup permitted?

Tags: discussion

Just trying to get the idea of what is/isnt allowed, but are installation and configuration questions about SharePoint permitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely! We cover "everything SharePoint" :-)

Comment: and thanks for correcting the capitalization, Internet Explorer (for some odd, unknown reason) doesn't autocapitalize 'SharePoint' when I'm using my autospellchecker.

Comment: you are welcome. And thanx for the moderation input :-)

Comment: if you mean the flags i just threw into the flags queue, well... *pfft* i do > 20 flags a day on Ask Ubuntu (I'm their moderators' worst nightmare when fighting the war against that little itty bitty number denoting the number of flags to deal with) (also, for the record, `/review` is awesome :P)... xD And if you mean thanking you for the spell correct, you're welcome. :)